# Azure AKS how to recreate node

Tags: azure, azure-aks

I deleted a windows node in AKS thinking it will recreate automatically, but it doesnt recreate.

Now, in portal.azure.com I see 2 in node count, but 1 in node ready.

[image: node count and node ready]

How can I recreate the node I deleted?

Comment: The AKS Upgrade might solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

*I tried to recreate the delete the nodes in my environment and got the below results*

I have created the resource group, container, and storage account

[image]

I have created the AKs cluster in that cluster I have the 1 node which is running the pods

[image]

I can use tool called ***VELERO*** to backup  the whole AKS cluster
Backup will be stored in the Azure storage account
I have created the credential file to configure the credentials in Velero.

```
cat << EOF  > /tmp/credentials-velero
AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_ACCESS_KEY=${AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_ACCESS_KEY}
AZURE_CLOUD_NAME=<any name>
EOF
```

I have installed the velero cilent using this [link](https://velero.io/docs/v1.6/basic-install/)
I have installed the velero on the aks cluster using below command

```
velero install \
--provider azure \
--plugins velero/velero-plugin-for-microsoft-azure:v1.1.0 \
--bucket $BLOB_CONTAINER \
--secret-file /tmp/credentials-velero \
--backup-location-config resourceGroup=$rg-name,storageAccount=$storage-name,storageAccountKeyEnvVar=access-key,subscriptionId=sub_id \
--use-volume-snapshots=false
```

I have deleted the nodes which I have created using below command

```
kubectl delete node node-name -n namespace-name
```

Now I have velero in Kubernetes I can create and schedule the backup

> To create the backup and schedule the backup and restore the backup

```
velero backup create kubernetes-cluster
velero backup create node-backup --include-resources nodepool
velero schedule create kubernetes-weekly --schedule="@weekly" --ttl 720h0m0s
velero schedule create pv-backup-weekly --schedule="@weekly" --include-resources node
velero restore create kubernetes-restore --from-backup kubernetes-cluster
velero restore create pvc-restore --from-backup pv-backup
```

> After backup the backup files will be stored in the containers of the storage account

[image]

Note: If we update the cluster to latest version also it will backup if we have the backup option